# Trying to make CommandButton in Microsoft Word open a hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

I have been having trouble trying to make a CommandButton object in my Word document redirect me to a website on click.
I have tried using VBA code like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlinkAddress:="MyWebsite.com"
End Sub
```

But to no avail. I think it might be because I took it directly from my Excel document.

Please Help me.

Ask any further questions you have.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word you want to use `ActiveDocument` instead of `ActiveWorkbook` for the file you're currently working with.  You also need the link protocol (ie- http://, https://, etc).  Try this instead:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  ActiveDocument.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://MyWebsite.com"
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! I did not think it was going to be as straightforward as that. Thank you @squillman so much for your quick reply, this has helped me immensely. Have a good day.

Comment: You're very welcome!